# MongoDB data model for fast reads using array data

Tags: mongodb

I have a dataset which returns an array named "data_arr" that contains anywhere from 5 to 200 subitems which have a labelspace & key-value pair as follows.

```
{
    "other_fields": "other_values",
    ...
    "data_arr":[
        {
           "labelspace": "A",
           "color": "red"
        },
        {
           "labelspace": "A",
           "size": 500
        },
        {
           "labelspace": "B",
           "shape": "round"
        },
    ]
}
```

The question is, within MongoDB, **how to store this data optimized for fast reads**. Specifically, there would be queries:

1. Comparing key-values (ie. Average size of objects which are both red
   and round).
2. Returning all documents which meet a criteria (ie. Red objects
   larger than 300).

Label space is important because some key names are reused.

I've contemplated indexing with the existing structure by indexing labelspace.

I've considered grouping all labelspace key/values into a single sub-document as follows:

```
{
    "other_fields": "other_values",
    ...
    "data_a":
        {
           "color": "red",
           "size": 500
        },
    "data_b":
        {
           "shape": "round"
        }
}
```

Or modeling it as follows with a multi-value index

```
{
    "other_fields": "other_values",
    ...
    "data_arr":[
        {
           "labelspace": "A",
           "key": "color",
           "value": "red"
        },
        {
           "labelspace": "A",
           "key": "size",
           "value": 500
        },
        {
           "labelspace": "B",
           "key": "shape",
           "value": "round"
        },
    ]
}
```

This is a new data set that needs to be collected. So it's difficult for me to build up enough of a sample only to discover I've ventured down the wrong path.

I think the last one is best suited for indexing, so possibly the best approach?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just unwind labelspaces into their own documents, with some top level key associating the two labelspaces, e.g. : `{ sharedKey: "abc", labelspace: "A", data_arr: [...]}, { sharedKey: "abc", labelspace: "B", data_arr: [...]}`. This would immediately eliminate some of your array index constraints.

Comment: That's another option, but then in the example above, looking for a red & round object would take a lookup operation. More expensive?

Comment: I'm confused as to the purpose of 'labelspace'. Are you going to query directly on those labelspaces, or are they only used to distinguish between repeat keys?

Comment: It's the way the source system returns data. In most cases, the keys are non-overlapping but that is not always true. In my example, it's possible that labelspace A says it's red, while labelspace B says it's blue. Beyond my control. But we would have an application rule like, just look for color within labelspace A only.

Comment: does that mean labelspace is shared across documents, i.e. doc1's labelspace "A" corresponds to doc2's labelspace "A"? As an aside, if you're just in data collection mode and not using it in app-specific code, I'd suggest just making a bunch relational collections with ID pointers. You can then restructure the data to serve your purposes without concern of having missed collecting something.